# Probability of $P(A \cup B \cup C)$.

Tags: probability

Let $A,B,C$ be events such that:

1. $P(A) = P(B) = P(C) = \frac{1}{2}$
2. $P(A \cap B) = P(A \cap C) = P( B \cap C) = \frac{1}{6}$

Determine $P(A \cap B \cap C)$.

I think that it is impossible because I don't know anything about $P(A \cup B \cup C)$.

Comment: **Hint**. You do know that $P(A\cup B\cup C)$ is at most $1$...

Comment: I think the question asks you to build upper and lower estimates on that probability.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I don't understand. Could you show me it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(A \cup B \cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A \cap B) - P(B \cap C) - P(A \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C)$$
But $$0 \leq P(A \cup B \cup C) \leq 1$$
Therefore,
$$0 \leq P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A \cap B) - P(B \cap C) - P(A \cap C) + P(A \cap B \cap C) \leq 1$$

What does that give you?

Comment: @TenaliRamanfrom yours inequality I have that $0  \le 1+ P(A \cap B \cap C) \le  1$ so this information doesen't help.

Comment: @user2213654 subtract 1 from both sides, what do you get?

Comment: Ok of course is equal $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know $P(A)$ and $P(A\cap B)$, you can compute $P(A \setminus B)$. Similarly you can compute $P(B\setminus C)$ and $P(C\setminus A)$. Looking at a Venn diagram, observe that $A\setminus B$ is mutually exclusive with $B\setminus C$ and $C\setminus A$. How much is the *total* probability of these three mutually exclusive events? How much probability is there left to distribute to the parts of the Venn diagram you *haven't* hit yet?

Comment: So I have $P(A  \setminus B) = P(B  \setminus C) = P(C  \setminus A) = \frac{1}{3}$. In Venn diagram I see that $A \cup B \cup C = (A  \setminus B) \cup (B  \setminus C) \cup (C  \setminus A) \cup (A \cap B \cap C)$. And what next?

Comment: @user2213654: What is $P((A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus C)\cup (C\setminus A))$? And so what is the probability that you're _not_ in one of these three cases?

Comment: To be honest I have no idea. If it is possible, could you tell me? I will grateful.

Comment: @user2213654: You're doing the exercise. Do you know the rule for finding $P(X\cup Y \cup Z)$ when $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are mutually exclusive?

Comment: So $P(X \cup Y \cup Z) = P(X)+P(Y) + P(Z)$. Hence $P((A \setminus B)  \cup (B \setminus C)  \cup (C \setminus A)) = 1$

Comment: @user2213654: Yes, and therefore nothing _outside_ this event can have nonzero probability.

Comment: Ok, now I understood yours idea. Thank's a lot.